# Oracle regexp pattern with specified number of strings between two phrases

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need a regexp which matches any occurrence of product "bebilon 3" in some descriptions of different products, like:

- "something bebilon 3 great for babies"
- "bebilon super extra 3 300g"
- "bebilon super 3 3x200g"
- "bebilon super 2 something"

I decided, that most of cases will fit in `bebilon (something){0,2} 3`

And wrote it like this:

```
regexp_like(description, 'bebilon ([^[:space:]]+){0,2} 3', 'i')
```

Am I correct? What will be better? I have some problems with spaces in this solution.

Comment: (regexp_like(it_name, 'bebilon ([^[:space:]]+ ){0,2}3', 'i')) - I've added a space after "+" sign. It matches "bebilon 3" and "bebilon something 3". A little better

Comment: Do you mean you must have the word "bebilon" by itself, and then the number 3 by itself? So for example 3 should not be part of the number 320, and "bebilons", "super-bebilon" etc. should not be accepted? How do you define "word" (you didn't use the term "word", but it is implicit in the requirement).

Comment: You get it right: "you must have the word "bebilon" by itself, and then the number 3 by itself? So for example 3 should not be part of the number 320, and "bebilons", "super-bebilon" etc. should not be accepted"

Answer (score 0):

```
... 
where regexp_like(description, ' bebilon( .+ | )3 ')
```

This will return every row where the description includes the characters `' bebilon '` and `' 3 '`. Note - you may have bebilon as the first word (and perhaps capitalized), and 3 might be the last character in the string, so the reg expr pattern may need to be modified. You need to present a comprehensive, exhaustive list of all possible special cases to consider, before a comprehensive, correct solution can be offered.

Note: `( .+ | )` means *either* a space, then one or more character, then a space, *or* exactly one space. This is what needs to be between bebilon and 3. (This does not allow for exactly two spaces and nothing else between bebilon and 3; if you want to allow that too, change `.+` to `.*`).

Comment: "." can be anything. It can also be 2, so as described in my example also "bebilon super 2 something" will fit and I want only "bebilon super 3 something". Because I need to distinguish two products: "bebilon 2" and "bebilon 3"

Comment: @bry888 - Of course `.` can be anything, that is why the pattern **also requires** the characters 3 and space at the end of the pattern. Did you see that? Also, if you have test data prepared somewhere already, you should be able to **test** what I provided very easily. Please test it and **then** ask questions.

Comment: I did so :) Just copied your solution and got "bebilon 2 something" in answers.

Comment: @bry888 - That wasn't the entire string (if you say it was, then I don't believe you, you don't believe me, so it's the end of discussion.) It was a fragment of a string, where you ALSO had the number 3 by itself, perhaps somewhere else in the string.

Comment: Are you saying your query should also EXCLUDE the occurrence of any other (single-digit?) numbers from the string, not just INCLUDE 3?

Comment: Ok, I'll describe it better: I have many descriptions of bebilon products. These products are "bebilon 1", "bebilon 2", "bebilon 3" and so on. Whole descriptions contain product name, but also some additional information which can be placed anywhere. This information is number of boxes/grams/advertisement-super-words or anything. But number of additional words between "bebilon" and "3" is maximum 2. With your solution for example I also got "something bebilon 6 after 3 years" - wrong

Comment: @bry888 - OK, we are getting somewhere. (By the way, do you understand now why I ask so many questions? I am sorry I even offered a solution **before** having all the answers, but in fact this helped the discussion.) So - new question: Is it possible to have any numbers between the word "bebilon" and the number 3 which you require? If it is not possible, then the solution can be adapted easily for the new requirement. But please confirm, so we don't need to change the solution repeatedly.